# Parsing DEX 894 and 895 files with EdiFabric

Tags: c#, edi, x12, edifabric

We're evaluating EdiFabric to parse DEX transmissions (it's a form of EDI but comes in from a DSD serial port).  The documents in question are EDI X12 894 and 895s.

How do we create a custom envelope in EdiFabric to support DEX headers. The envelope starts with DXS and ends with DXE.  NEX starts with ISA, so it's a little different.
How can I use a custom envelope, or create a template or whatever to parse incoming 894 and 895 files wrapped this way?

Here's an example transmission.  Note the DXS and DXE envelope.

```
DXS*4285050000*DX*005010UCS*1003*9876543210*P
ST*894*0001
G82*D*101250062*006922009*1610*118481269*001610*20220817**
LS*0100
G83*1*1*CA**UP*840262400077**28.50*12*MTN DEW HARD ZS BAJA*UP*840262400084
G83*2*1*CA**UP*840262400053**28.50*12*MTN DEW HARD ZS BLKC*UP*840262400060
G83*3*1*CA**UP*840262400015**28.50*12*MTN DEW HARD ZS ORG*UP*840262400022
G83*4*1*CA**UP*840262400138**30.20*2*MTN DEW HARD ZS VAR*UP*840262400145
G83*5*1*CA**UP*840262400039**28.50*12*MTN DEW HARD ZS WTRM*UP*840262400145
LE*0100
G84*5*14420*0
G86*00*WINTER HAVEN, FL
G85*8267
SE*13*0001
DXE*1003*1
```

This is kind of a niche topic so here's a little more info:

> DEX, Direct Exchange, is a form of electronic data interchange, EDI,
> used by direct store delivery, DSD, distributors to electronically
> send their delivery information, invoices and or credit memos, to the
> retailer at the time of delivery.  DEX is the industry standard  where
> any vendor who is DEX capable is able to electronically send their
> invoices to any retailer that is DEX capable, regardless of who that
> vendor or retailer is using for their DEX software.  DEX has been
> around for many years and is used by all major grocery retailers as
> well as numerous smaller chains and convenience stores.

Answer (score 0):

According to EdiFabric's support - they do not support DEX at this time.

Comment: For those stumbling upon this post, we used EDI.NET instead.